# how to detect ContextMenu disappear event OR how to keep ContextMenu if user does not select an item

Tags: android, contextmenu

This is my first time asking a question here. If this question has been asked before, please tell me and I will delete this thread. ^_^

I have registered a ContextMenu for a ListView in Android. The simple logic is:

1. If I touch a ListView item, a ContextMenu pops up and the item color is changed (indicating that this row is selected). I have implemented this within the onCreateContextMenu() method.

```js
@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        blablabla...
  row.setBackgroundColor(Color_Selected);
  blablabla...
}
```

2. After the user selects the options in the ContextMenu (e.g. edit or cancel), the item color is changed to its previous color. This is implemented in the onContextItemSelected() method.

```js
@Override
      public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      blablabla...
      table.setBackgroundColor(Color_Original); 
            blablabla...
     }
```

My question is: if I touch somewhere else on the screen(not an option of the ContextMenu), the ContextMenu disappears, however the selected row color is not changed back! Therefore I want to know if there is a method like onContextMenuDestroyed() method so that I can change the color back in this method. Another option will be that I keep the ContextMenu appear on the screen until the user selects an option within it.

Thank you!